# Какие возможные причины появления ошибки Forbidden: bot was kicked from the group chat?

Tags: telegram-bot

Есть бот, который рассылает уведомления в приватные группы.
Возникла проблема, при отправке сообщения получаю ошибку **Forbidden: bot was kicked from the group chat**.
Бот добавлен в группу со всеми правами. Повторное добавление не помогает.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Так, может, ошибка из какой-то другой группы?

Comment: @andreymal Ответ 403 приходит именно для этой группы. Это тестовая группа, бот работает локально. За сегодня 2 раза сталкивался с этой проблемой.